# How to find the 100 largest GitHub repositories for a past date?

Tags: git, github, open-source

I am trying to understand the evolution of the 100 largest repositories on GitHub. I can easily access the 100 largest repositories as of today (as measured per total number of contributors, stars, forks or LOC) using the GitHub search function or GithubArchive.org.

However, I would like to look at the 100 largest repositories at a given data in history (say, 1st of April 2011), so that I can track their growth (or decline) from that point on. How can I identify the 100 largest repositories on GitHub (as measured per stars, forks, or LOC) for a date in the past?

Comment: So any result on this one? I am also interested to keep track of starring as a mean to follow technology trends. To be able to recognize emerging things like AngularJS and also stagnating like jQuery

Comment: What do you mean? The question is answered and the best answer has been selected...

Comment: I can't see stars or watches there

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the GitHub archive project can be of help: http://www.githubarchive.org/

It stores all the public events from the GitHub timeline and exposes them for processing. The events contain info about the repositories, so you should be able to pull the data out of there to fit your use-case.

For example, I've just used the following query in the BigQuery console ( https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/?pli=1 ) to find out the number of forks of the joyent/node repository for the date 2012-03-15:

```
SELECT repository_forks, created_at FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline] WHERE (repository_url = "https://github.com/joyent/node") AND (created_at CONTAINS "2012-03-15") LIMIT 1
```

At here are the results:

```
Row forks   created_at   
1   1579    2012-03-15 07:49:54
```

Obiously, you would use the BigQuery API to do something similar (extract the data you want, fetch data for a range of dates, etc.).

And here is a query for fetching the single largest repository (by forks) for a given date:

```
SELECT repository_forks, repository_url FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline] WHERE (created_at CONTAINS "2012-03-15") ORDER BY repository_forks DESC LIMIT 1
```

Result:

```
Row forks   repository_url   
1   6341    https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife
```

And here is the query to fetch the top 100 repositories by forks for a given date:

```
SELECT MAX(repository_forks) as forks, repository_url FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline] WHERE (created_at CONTAINS "2012-03-15") GROUP BY repository_url ORDER BY forks DESC LIMIT 100
```

Result:

```
Row forks   repository_url   
1   6341    https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife   
2   4452    https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap     
3   3647    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew     
4   2888    https://github.com/rails/rails
...
```

Comment: If you read my comment you can see that I am already aware of githubarchive.org. However, it does not help me much to answer the question.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was late :). I extended my answer with an example that will fetch you the number of forks for a specific repo and a specific date.

Is this what you want or do you want to fetch the single largest repo on all GitHub for a specific date?

Comment: I just added an example for fetching the single largest repo (by forks) for a given date :).

Comment: If I run this query with DESC LIMIT 100, it will just give me a small number of results, since for a given date there might be several different numbers of forks at different times during the day. Can you edit the query so that it gives the 100 largest repositories by the end of that day?

Comment: Yep, added it to the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. However - I have been told by others that  writing thank you etc. clutters the comments - upvoting and accepting answers is the way you say "thank you" on SE, that was my understanding. I have upvoted your answer, and will accept it once I see that no other answers are coming in.

Comment: This works for 2012 data, but it does not work for 2011 data. Are there anyways of accessing the number of forks at a given time period from the GitHub API?

Comment: Short and sour - no. As far as I know, githubarchive is the only archive of historical data for GH repos.